# After hiding navbar, touches aren't recognized where the navbar was

Tags: ios, uipageviewcontroller

I have a `UIPageViewController` which has a root view controller and a data view controller (the xcode template).

I have two tap gesture recognizers on the main view in the data view controller.

I have an image view embedded in a scroll view which is embedded in the main view.

A single tap hides the navbar and a double tap zooms the image. I am unable to use either gesture recognizer where the navbar was after it is hidden.

Is there a way to enable the gesture recognizers in this space when the navbar is hidden or did I just miss a step? 
It's like the root view controller has blocked that area out; the gesture recognizers work perfectly everywhere else. I can post code if needed.

Comment: @Alex- Thank you for the edit! Sorry, it's late so I'm a little groggy. I appreciate the help.